# Mounting share Problems Ubuntu running on Windows 10 in VMWare

Tags: 20.04, mount, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS running in VMWare Workstation 15 Pro on a Windows 10.
In that Ubuntu I have a Plex Server running.

I use vmhgfs-fuse in the fstab to mount the shared folders to certain points and that has been working fine for some time now.
But lately I'm having troubles with the mounts. I've noticed that after a reboot of the VM at least one folder is not mounted correctly.
When I show the list of mounted folders I get:

`ls cannot access '<folder-name_1>' : Input/output error`

or

`ls: cannot access '<folder-name_1>': Transport endpoint is not connected`

I have a file for every folder to remount. When I do that for the folder that isn't mounted correctly I get:

`fusermount: failed to unmount <folder-path>: Invalid argument`

`Error -107 cannot open connection!`

Though after a few tries the errors disappear and it will remount. To check I list the folders and their contents again.
Sure enough the folder(s) in question is/are mounted again.

But, then a different, already mounted folder at boot, will go nuts and I get the same message with "Input/output error" or "Transport endpoint ..." for that one or even two.

That goes on and on and on and on, until eventually maybe I have all of them mounted without problems or I just give up and leave the least relevant one(s) unmounted.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?
I can't say when it started, but I believe it might have something to do with the amount of folders I'm sharing/mounting. Started out with maybe 5 and now there's 11. Had 13 of them but removed 2 in hope that it would solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 would imply you're a year behind (*or more*) on security fixes & patches?  Are you sure that's what you're using (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.4 but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before that date, & fully upgraded systems report as 20.04.5; your lack of updates may also indicate poor choices you've made & thus help explain issues; why are you that far behind on security fixes?)

Comment: Feel utterly stupid for asking with the system not up to date...
Meanwhile with the system up to date, it still does not work. Doesn't surprise me, since it worked at some point. But as I mentioned there were about 5 shares back then.
Will reduce the amount of shares one by one and hope it stops at some point to pin point the "threshold" and see if that's the problem.
But also if it is. I don't see why 10 shares should be a problem and I don't understand that the errors and the behavior are trying to tell me.